# Where can I find an open source C# project that uses ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, database, open-source, ado.net

I am trying to write a Windows Form and ASP.NET C# front-end and MSAccess backend for a pretty small database concept I have.

I have written this application once before in just MSAccess but I now need the app and database to be in different places. I have now figured out (thanks to a StackOverflow user) that ADO will be a bad choice because it has to have a connection open all of the time.

I bought Microsoft ADO.Net 2.0 Step-by-Step and I have read through some of it and understand (I think) the basic concepts at play in ADO.NET. (Datasets and the like)

Where I get confused is the actual implementation. What I want to know is do any of you know of a C# project that has a database backend which is open source that I can go look at the code and see how they did it. I find I learn better that way. The book has a CD with code examples that I may turn to, but I would rather see real code in a real app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this but it looks like it might be a good fit:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DBaseFactGenerics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MySQL .net connector.  It is the nuts and bolts of how the ADO.net classes talk to the DB engine.  ADO.net as a whole does not keep connections open.  Certain higher level classes do.  Technically the lower level objects such as the connection and command objects are part of ADO.net, but you have a high degree of control over them.

Answer (score 0):

Check CodePlex, they have a ton of .NET projects.  I can't think of specific ones that fit your requirements, but you should be able to find something.

www.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I found this post http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx by searching for ADO.NET on the codeproject so I am going to give Chris Porter the answer points. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer points, I can finally comment!!  To add value to this comment, I'll offer a quick tip regarding codeproject.  The search feature on CP is a bit cumbersome at times so I recommend searching the site using google and prefixing the search with "site:www.codeproject.com "