# Implementing an ADO.NET layer

Tags: ado.net

Are there any tutorials or how-to's that explain how to implement an ADO.NET layer?

That would include implementing a Connection class, etcetera.

I need to do this because I am querying an old proprietary system and I want to wrap the old APIs properly.

Answer (score 1):

See "Building a Custom Data Provider for Use with the .NET Data Access Framework" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301611.aspx

Also, Googling for "Custom ADO.NET Data Provider" should give you many possible answers.

Comment: This link is really really old and out of date. I ended up redoing all the stuff they suggested because it's the wrong way to do it at the moment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - did you Google to get more methods as I suggested?

Comment: Also - if you find a better answer, post it here so others can benefit and not use Microsoft's outdated answer.

Comment: The broken link is for the December 2001 issue of *MSDN Magazine* (vol. 16, #12, for the record), but the code was based on the original ADO.NET (not 2.0) so it's now irrelevant anyway. However, in 2004 the author of the article, Bob Beauchemin, created an updated version of his sample  data provider for ADO.NET 2.0. Discussion at https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/a-sample-ado-net-2-0-data-provider/ and https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/expose-data-through-an-ado-net-data-provider/. Direct link to zip: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/content/binary/mdirprov2_for_net2.zip

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question similar to this a while back. You may want to read through the answers there. The person who actually answered the question posted a link to a code project article that did a great job of explaining ado when working with MSAcess.

[Where can I find an open source C# project that uses ADO.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167746/where-can-i-find-an-open-source-c-project-that-uses-ado-net)